# Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes in Unity3D returns extra ZEROs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, encoding

```
char[] chars = new char[]
{
    (char)0xd83d, (char)0xde04,
};
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(chars);
Console.WriteLine("bytes.Length = " + bytes.Length);

foreach (var b in bytes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(b.ToString("x2"));
}
```

Run this code in Visual studio, output is

```
bytes.Length = 4
04
f6
01
00
```

But in Unity, output is

```
bytes.Length = 8
04
f6
01
00
00
00
00
00
```

Why is that?

B.T.W. 0xd83d, 0xde04 is an Emoji. It should equal to Unicode U+1F604, so I think `bytes.Length` should be 4 (an UInt32).

----------------edit---------------------------------

In Visual Studio, `Encoding.UTF32.GetChars(the 4 bytes)` returns original chars back

But in Unity, `Encoding.UTF32.GetChars(the 8 bytes)` returns different chars

So I think this is a bug

Comment: I'm getting the same behavior. Strange

Comment: @SimpleVar It seems there is no solution.

Comment: I also posted this question here
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1282293/encodingutf32getbytes-in-unity-returns-extra-zeros.html#comment-1282490
but no answers until now

Answer (score 1):

Right click the `.ToString("x2")` and then "Go to definition".

You'll see that on a regular VS project you'll get to:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\mscorlib.dll`

But on a Unity project you'll get to:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v3.5\Profile\Unity Subset v3.5\mscorlib.dll`

---

I doubt the framework version (3.5 vs 4.5) is the reason. I suppose the "unity subset" is implemented differently.

Now, if you ask why the unity subset's dll implements it the way that it does - I do not know.

Comment: `byte.ToString` actually has nothing to do with it, but its a similar story with `Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes`

Comment: I tried changing 'Target Framework' to '.Net Framework 3.5' in Visual Studio, still got right result.

Comment: I have run this Unity test on Android and iOS (IL2CPP), result was the same.

Comment: That's just disturbing. Do let me know if there's a "real fix"

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the encoding maybe snuck a null terminator in there. Separating the 32-bit values:

```
0x04 0xf6 0x01 0x00  // 0x0001f604
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00  // 0x00000000 (NUL)
```

If the top line seems confusing, that's because the byte order is little-endian.

So, `Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes` first outputs the UTF-16 surrogate pair as a UTF-32 character correctly as it should, and appends a null character.

Unfortunately I can't test this right now as I don't have a compatible machine, but try the following:

1. Add the surrogate pairs `(char)0xd83d, (char)0xde04` twice into the `char` array and run the same program – if the length of `bytes` is 12 and the last four bytes are all zeroes my answer is plausible, if the length is 16 (and the bytes are just the same eight byte sequence twice) it would seem that the compiler for some reason uses 64-bit `UInt`s for UTF-32 characters.
2. Consider following [Microsoft's suggestion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5881c0k9(v=vs.110).aspx):

   > Consider using the [Encoder.Convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoder.convert(v=vs.110).aspx) method instead of GetByteCount. The conversion method converts as much data as possible, and does throw an exception if the output buffer is too small. For continuous encoding of a stream, this method is often the best choice.

Comment: `char[] chars = new char[]
{
    (char)0xd83d, (char)0xde04,
    (char)0xd83d, (char)0xde04,
};`

output


`04, f6, 01, 00`
`04, f6, 01, 00`
`00, 00, 00, 00`
`00, 00, 00, 00`

Comment: Hm, that was unexpected.